# Text Size Slider with AngularJS for specific element

Tags: angularjs

I have create directive for range slider, right now it change body font but i want to work for specific element, can you give me code for that

```
angular.module('textSizeSlider', [])
       .directive('textSizeSlider', ['$document', function ($document) {
            return {
              restrict: 'E',
              template: '<div class="text-size-slider"><span class="small-letter" ng-style="{ fontSize: min + unit }">A</span> <input type="range" min="{{ min }}" max="{{ max }}" step="{{ step || 0 }}" ng-model="textSize" class="slider" value="{{ value }}" /> <span class="big-letter" ng-style="{ fontSize: max + unit }">A</span></div>',
              scope: {
                min: '@',
                max: '@',
                unit: '@',
                value: '@',
                step: '@'
              },
              link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                scope.textSize = scope.value;
                scope.$watch('textSize', function (size) {
                  $document[0].body.style.fontSize = size + scope.unit;
                });
              }
            }
          }]);
```

Comment: do you want to handle child `font-size` which dependent on scale parent?

Comment: @Maher check this link i want to change only heading font size

https://plnkr.co/edit/9bYR1aprS3Xn7YWyB6kj?p=preview

Comment: Anyone can me give me answer???

Comment: do you want make it with jquery or jquery light?

Comment: @Maher i want to make with angularjs only

Answer (score 0):

> Add **target** in your directive to make it dynamic.
>
> Add **id="*"** to your target to detect it with JavaScript DOM.

**Html**

```
<header ng-app="textSizeSlider">
    <!-- Custom AngularJS Directive -->
    <text-size-slider min="12" max="24" unit="px" value="18" step="0" target="myHeaderTitle">
        <!-- END of Custom AngularJS Directive -->
    </text-size-slider>
</header>

<section>
    <h1 id="myHeaderTitle">Text Size Slider</h1>
    <h3>AngularJS, HTML5 and CSS3</h3>
    <article>
        <p>
            <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

**change directive to**

```
return {
controller: ctrl,
restrict: 'E',
template: '<div class="text-size-slider"><span class="pointer" style="left:{{position}}px;"><span>{{textSize}}</span></span><span class="small-letter" ng-style="{ fontSize: min + unit }">A</span> <input type="range" min="{{ min }}" max="{{ max }}" step="{{ step || 0 }}" ng-model="textSize" class="slider" value="{{ value }}" ng-change="updatepointer()" /> <span class="big-letter" ng-style="{ fontSize: max + unit }">A</span></div>',
scope: {
    min: '@',
    max: '@',
    unit: '@',
    value: '@',
    step: '@',
    target: '@'
},
link: function (scope, element, attr) {
    scope.textSize = scope.value;

    scope.$watch('textSize', function (size) {
        document.getElementById(scope.target).style.fontSize = size + scope.unit;
        scope.updatepointer();
    });
}
}
```

> If you have **more than one** element **to change** size or other styles use this

**Change directive target attribute by this:**

```
target="myHeaderTitle,myHeaderTitle2"
```

**define the targets**

```
<h1 id="myHeaderTitle">Text Size Slider</h1>
<h3 id="myHeaderTitle2">AngularJS, HTML5 and CSS3</h3>
```

**Change the Directive by this codes:**

```
var targets = scope.target.split(",");

scope.$watch('textSize', function (size) {
    for (key in targets) {
        var target = targets[key];
        document.getElementById(target).style.fontSize = size + scope.unit;
    }
    scope.updatepointer();
});
```

Comment: i have add your code but not working yet, please check codepen

https://codepen.io/tarunmishra592/pen/PmMbxx

Comment: Target is Id not class

Comment: Not working with multiple elements check codepen link below also giving console error
https://codepen.io/tarunmishra592/pen/PmMbxx

Comment: That because you do this by repeating the id and Id is unique and in your question you didn't talk about repeat elements, I'm on mobile now I will answer you soon as possible